# how to create Custom Keyboard UIButton having pop-up shortcuts

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uibutton

i am planning to make the buttons on my custom keyboard as shown in the images in the following link http://www.macaddict.com/article/howtos/iphone_and_ipad_tips_week_keyboard_shortcuts .
 i am using the custom keyboard extension. i have done research but found just one post about this but it was unanswered.

sorry i couldn't post an image, i have less than 10 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you doesn't provide and code I can only suggest you library for that.

[Tasty Imitation Keyboard](https://github.com/archagon/tasty-imitation-keyboard) is what you exactly need and here is the result of that keyboard library:

for portrait:

[image]

for landscape:

[image]

Comment: no i mean the same pop up but with different choices to pic for example ... for the A key you can choose , à á â ä æ ã å å

Comment: I will inform you If I found something similer like that..:)

Comment: Happy to help you..:)